# Convert int into enum without being able to typecast

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, casting, type-conversion

Is there a way to convert an integer into an enum without giving the type? Like:

*Convert given int into the enum value that the enum is storing as representing value for the given int.*

I know the exact enum type but cannot reference it in my scope since the access is not possible due to the degree of protection.
Changing the degree of protection is not an option either.

I know I should never do this but sadly there is literally no other way in this case.

EDIT ( Further Information):

I am modifying an Unity Game. A Class of the game has a private Enum defining different states and a private field, that stores a state. The field is later on used and I want to change the state stored in the field. 
To do so, I am using Harmony ( a library used to patch code at Runtime) and I successfully changed a lot of things with it's help. I access this field with the help of reflection and now want to typecast an int to the certain state stored in the Enum.

Comment: I do not understand what it means to convert something to a type without actually using the type. It seems contradictory. Perhaps you could provide a code example that demonstrates what you are trying to do? What do you plan to do with this variable after you have converted it?

Comment: Hm… sounds like you originally want to do sonething like ``MyEnum enumVal = MyEnum.Whatever`` but you do not have access to use ``MyEnum.Whatever``. Right? Or is it even worse, and you do not have access to ``MyEnum``?

Comment: @JohnWu Gave some more context!

Comment: @dumetrulo What I want to do is something like this:

int IntegerToEnum = 0;
PrivateEnum enumState = (PrivateEnum) IntegerToEnum;

Having no access to PrivateEnum.

Comment: An `enum` is essentially a namespace with named `int` constants and provides some helpful assurances about that enum's possible values when compiling. You can use ILSpy to see if the `PrivateEnum` type is using a different storage type than `int`, but that's the default if not explicitly defined. *How* exactly are you using this `PrivateEnum` value outside the class? Why is an `int` not sufficient? It's all the same to the machine, `enum` is just "syntactic sugar". If you just want to set a private field in a class, you don't need the `PrivateEnum` type at all.

Comment: OP, There is no way to cast a variable to a type that is not referenced, as casting is a compile-time concept. But 99% of the time you can work with an enum of any type by treating it as an `int`.